# How to create a calendar in windows phone with days view,month view,week view,year view

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am creating a calendar application for windows phone,So far I created a simple calendar using wpcontrols but I can not add month view , year view ,week view in wpcontrols or some other usercontrols.

I want to create my calendar control like native calendar.

[image]

How Can I create a rich calendar for windows phone

Comment: What exactly is your question? This is very broad.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir,I want to create a windows phone calendar with month and week views.

Comment: Ya we get your intent, but you didn't really name a specific problem you're having but instead a very broad one that would likely require a very long and detailed answer. Stackoverflow is aimed more towards specific questions looking for specific answers. You will have trouble finding someone to answer such a broad question.

Comment: Oh sorry for my trouble. Is there any way to ask this question as much as simple, please edit this...

Comment: You might want to break it up into multiple questions, show what you've tried as you go and approach it as one problem at a time instead of one big issue all at once...and no trouble, this is why we all use SO, to help each other out. :)

Comment: thanks sir....I did this.